# TypeORM Postgres - there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am getting the error:

```
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
```

My models are as follows:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    userId: string

    @OneToMany(() => Position, position => position.user)
    positions: Position[]
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Position {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    positionId: number

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.positions)
    user: User
}
```

It seems like using the UUID strategy might be the error? But I also noted that the generated query defines the userID column with PK contraint:

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_d72ea127f30e21753c9e229891e" PRIMARY KEY ("userId")
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I realise there is some polluted migration files inside of `/dist` that was messing with the database. After deleting `/dist` and having all files regenerated, the problem was gone.

Polluted `/dist` is apparently a problem not well looked into and can affect tsnode-dev, typescript, nodemon, and nestjs dev instances that generates `/dist` on the fly and incrementally.